# Overleaf Formatting Deletion and Corruption

Tags: overleaf

This is one of the most confusing problems that I have ever had with a coding language. I am writing a report on arithmetic geometry at the moment, and seemingly completely at random a paragraph or two will be attacked by overleaf and corrupted. Here is an example of the original code that I wrote correctly:

```
A \textit{Jacobi sum} is a function that sends a sequence of multiplicative characters
 $(\chi_{1}, \ldots, \chi_{l})$ to $J(\chi_{1}, \ldots, \chi_{l})=
\sum_{a_1+\ldots+a_{l}=1}\chi_{1}(a_1)\ldots \chi_l(a_l)$
```

Which when run in overleaf successfully yields:

A *Jacobi sum* is a function that sends a sequence of multiplicative characters
$(\chi_{1}, \ldots, \chi_{l})$ to $J(\chi_{1}, \ldots, \chi_{l})=
\sum_{a_1+\ldots+a_{l}=1}\chi_{1}(a_1)\ldots \chi_l(a_l)$

However, seemingly completely at random, overleaf took this block of text and removed the $ for formatting, and also randomly added a copy of each formatted section before it, with ASCII characters.

```
A \textit{Jacobi sum} is a function that sends a sequence of multiplicative characters
 (χ1,…,χl)(\chi_{1}, \ldots, \chi_{l}) to J(χ1,…,χl)=∑a1+…+al=1χ1(a1)…χl(al)
J(\chi_{1}, \ldots, \chi_{l})=\sum_{a_1+\ldots+a_{l}=1}\chi_{1}(a_1)\ldots \chi_l(a_l)
```

This has happened to a larger swathe of the document. The original code compiles without error fine at first, and then randomly after about 5-10 minutes a random paragraph (almost always one written recently, though) gets annihilated by this bug. Has anyone ever experienced this? Does anybody have any clue what is going on?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the Overleaf support?

Comment: I have contacted them, I was wondering if any other people have ever encountered anything as strange as this.

Answer (score 6):

overleaf doesn't format your pdf output it just hosts texlive and provides an editor.  The editor has two modes

Code (your actual tex markup)

[image]

Visual (a kind of rich text view hiding some of the markup)

[image]

This latter (which you seem to show in your question) is just an editor view the underlying file is not changed in any way.

As noted in comments, if you see latex rendering in the source editor, it’s likely due to a browser extension.

Comment: Thanks for the info. To clarify, my issue is nothing to do with the output. The random deletions/additions are happening directly in the code editor.

Comment: @Michael check you are not in visual editor mode (which personally I wouldn't ever use, _by design_ it hides some markup and shows other markup)

Comment: This happens when you have the “TeX All the Things” browser extension activated. … so not Overleaf behaviour.

Comment: ah @DanMacKinnon. Just to clarify, by "this happens"  you meant the behaviour the OP described, not what I show here (which is an unextended firefox). Do you want to post a more informed OverLeaf  answer (I have never heard of that extension) and I'll happily delete this one?

Comment: Sorry , yes @DavidCarlisle - this comment should have been addressed to the original post, not your answer. Your answer is helpful… if anything I’d just add “if you see latex rendering in the source editor , it’s likely due to a browser extension”

Comment: @DanMacKinnon added, thanks:-)